# What happens to the beans that have already created when context is closed

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Can some one please enlighten me on what happens to the beans that have already created  when context is closed .

Beans are destroyed means should  not they be removed from the memory ?Or else is it just the container stops managing the beans that were initially created ?

Answer (score 1):

The context when closing will call the destroy method of the bean (if it has one). This gives the bean a chance to clean up any other resources it may use (for example open connections).

Eventually, when beans are no longer referenced from anywhere in the program they will be garbage collected by the JVM. This is just the same as with any other object. There is nothing special about beans.